# Postgresql find aggregated maximum value by different times

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where I store the following:

```
uuid, client_code, account, item, quantity, timestamp
```

Every time an item quantity is updated somewhere else, a new record is created in this table and items can be repeated by account from the client, so I could end up with several records per client for the same or different accounts with the same item, but different quantity.

I'm trying to come up with a query that would give me the maximum aggregated quantities by client and the time. As an example:

| Timestamp | item | quantity | account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01T01:00:10 | 1245 | 10 | a |
| 2024-01-01T05:00:10 | 1245 | 300 | a |
| 2024-01-01T04:00:10 | 1245 | 20 | b |
| 2024-01-01T07:00:10 | 1111 | 30 | a |

For this example, it'd need to return that the highest quantity for item `1245` was at 2024-01-01T05:00:10 with 320, 300 from account a, and 20 from account b since it was the latest movement.
For item `1111` the highest quantity was at 2024-01-01T07:00:10 with a total quantity of 30.

I've tried to figure this out many times but I ended nowhere.

Could someone help to see how this could be achieved? Thanks!

Tried several queries, windows functions, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can look back from a correlated [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES). [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/6RCsMj4v)

```sql
select *,(select sum(quantity)
          from(select distinct on (account) quantity
               from my_table t2
               where t1.item=t2.item
                 and t1.timestamp>=t2.timestamp
               order by account,timestamp desc)_)
from my_table t1
order by timestamp;
```

| timestamp | item | quantity | account | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 01:00:10 | 1245 | 10 | a | 10 |
| 2024-01-01 04:00:10 | 1245 | 20 | b | 30 |
| 2024-01-01 05:00:10 | 1245 | 300 | a | 320 |
| 2024-01-01 07:00:10 | 1111 | 30 | a | 30 |

In each row it uses [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) to grab one latest quantity of the same item from each account, then sums those up.

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation correctly, the subquery will only ever return one value per item, however I could have many more then that. I just kept it to one in the example to make it more readable

Comment: You can have as many items, dates and accounts as you wish. The `distinct on` above gets one value *per item, per account*, then those are collected into *one sum* to be returned to each individual row of the outer query. I’m not sure what in your understanding of the doc worries you but I think it would be easiest to discuss a specific example: try to come up with a set of rows that you expect this to fail on (produce undesired results), and attach them to the question. You can also add them to [my demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6RCsMj4v) click `run` to generate a new link, then share that link.